# How to load data from file binary search tree in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, load, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I use the read and write to load and save file from the tree. Why when i save the employee to the notepad is work. But I cannot load it into the node again to display it when I run. Can anybody help me? Is there any problem with my read function? I don't know how to read data from file txt to the tree and load it when i run.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;

class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int ID;
        private String name;
        String  address;
        public Employee getName;

        Employee(int emp_ID, String emp_name, String emp_address){
            ID = emp_ID;
            name = emp_name;
            address = emp_address;
        }
        public void print(){
            System.out.println(ID);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(address);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ID + "-" + name + "-" + address;
         }

         public int getID ( )
         {
             return ID;
         }

         public void setID (int emp_ID)
         {
             ID = emp_ID;           
         }  

         public String getName ( )
         {
             return name;
         }

         public void setName (String emp_Name)
         {
             name = emp_Name;           
         }

         @Override
         public int compareTo(Employee o) {     
            return 0;
         }

         public void input() {
            System.out.print("Please input an Employee \n");
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input an Employee ID");
            ID = myScanner.nextInt();
            myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please input an Employee Name");
            name = myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please input an Employee Address");
            address = myScanner.nextLine();
          }
    }
 }

 /* Class BST */
 class BST
 {
     private Node root;

     /* Constructor */
     public BST()
     {
         root = null;
     }
     /* Function to check if tree is empty */
     public boolean isEmpty()
     {
         return root == null;
     }
     /* Functions to insert data */
     public void insert(Employee emp)
     {
         root = insert(root, emp);
     }
     /* Function to insert data recursively */
     private Node insert(Node node, Employee emp)
     {
         if (node == null)
             node = new Node(emp);
         else
         {
             if (emp.getID() <= node.getID())
                 node.left = insert(node.left, emp);
             else
                 node.right = insert(node.right, emp);
         }
         return node;
     }
     /* Functions to delete data */

     /* Functions to count number of nodes */

     /* Functions to search for an element */

     /* Function to search for an element recursively */

     /* Function for inorder traversal */
     public void inorder()
     {
         inorder(root);
     }
     private void inorder(Node r)
     {
         if (r != null)
         {
             inorder(r.getLeft());
             System.out.print(r.getData() +" ");
             inorder(r.getRight());
         }
     }
     /* Function for preorder traversal */
     public void preorder()
     {
         preorder(root);
     }

     private void preorder(Node r)
     {
         if (r != null)
         {
             System.out.print(r.getData() +" ");
             preorder(r.getLeft());             
             preorder(r.getRight());
         }
     }
     /* Function for postorder traversal */
     public void postorder()
     {
         postorder(root);
     }

     private void postorder(Node r)
     {
         if (r != null)
         {
             postorder(r.getLeft());             
             postorder(r.getRight());
             System.out.print(r.getData() +" ");
         }
     }

     public static int Read() {
         int count=0;
         try{
             Vector<Employee> vector = new Vector<Employee>();
             FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("D:/info.txt");
             ObjectInputStream save;
             try{
                 for(;;){
                     save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
                     Employee emp = (Employee) save.readObject();
                     vector.add(emp);
                     count++;
                 }
             }catch(EOFException e){
                 //e.printStackTrace();
             }
             saveFile.close(); 

         }catch(Exception exc){
             exc.printStackTrace();
         }
         return count;
     }

     public void Write(Employee mm) {
         try
           {
             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/info.txt",true);
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut));

             out.writeObject(mm);            
             out.close();
             fileOut.close();
             System.out.println("Serialized data is saved in info.ser");
           }catch(IOException i)
           {
               //i.printStackTrace();
           }
     }
 }

 /* Class BinarySearchTree */
 public class Binary
 { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        Employee emp = null;

        int ID = 0;

        String name = null;
        int uID = 0;
        String address = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        /* Creating object of BST */
        BST bst = new BST(); 

        System.out.println("Binary Search Tree Test\n");          
        char ch;
        /*  Perform tree operations  */
        do    
        {
            System.out.println("\nBinary Search Tree Operations\n");
            System.out.println("1. insert ");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();            
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1 : 
                System.out.print("Please input an Employee \n");

                System.out.println("Please input an Employee ID");
                ID = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Name");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please input an Employee Address");
                address = scan.nextLine();
                emp = new Employee(ID,name,address);
                bst.insert(emp);
                bst.Write(emp);
                break;                          
            default : 
                System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
                break;   
            }
            /*  Display tree  */ 
            System.out.print("\nPost order : ");
            bst.postorder();
            System.out.print("\nPre order : ");
            bst.preorder();
            System.out.print("\nIn order : ");
            bst.inorder();

            System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
            ch = scan.next().charAt(0);                        
        } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');               
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I don't know how to read data from file txt to the tree and load it when i run."

soo it seems that you are simply trying to write the BST into a .txt file and then read from that .txt file to construct the BST?

Both reading and writing methods must agree with each other (how you read from the file depends on the format in which the .txt file was written):

an example for writing the BST to a .txt file:

```
public static void main() {
    BST tree = //constructed BST
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(//name of file to write to));
    tree.write(output); // to write the tree to a file
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(//file name goes here);
    tree.read(input); // to construct the tree from a file
}
```

so an example of writing in the format:
value
value
etc...

```
    public void write(PrintStream output) {
        write(overallRoot, "", output);
    }

    private void write(TreeNode root, String code, PrintStream output) {
        if(root != null) {
            if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                output.println(root.data + "\n");
            }
            // recursive-case 
            write(root.left, output);
            write(root.right, output);
        }
    }
```

and then if you want to read from the file with that format...

```
public void read(FileInputStream input) {
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(input.nextLine()); //read from file line by line
    tree.insert(node); // use a BST insert method to build the tree node by node
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. But i still cannot write the read it reports an error when I use the method TreeNode(input.nextLine()); And my insert function look  like the following code how can i reuse it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm guessing the error that you are getting is an inputmismatchexception() because your example is a TreeNode<Employee>.. so you must construct an Employee type with the parsed string values.